# Getting Revision History from Google drive API in .Net

Tags: c#, wpf, revision-history, google-drive-api

I am creating WPF application and I am using Google drive API for uploading and downloading files. As the G-mail provides Revision History for files on drive, I also want to implement it in my project and get the detailed list of revisions for a file. Is there some kind of event for this? Can anyone tell me how this work and how can I implement it in my application? And how to revert to the previous version of the file?...

I found answer for the above and also mentioned it in the comments.

I want to use revision history in the scenario like:
I have uploaded a document on Google drive of around(or more) 500 MB and another user 
downloads it on their PC and changes 2-3 lines in that document and then upload it again so
instead of uploading the entire document I want the changed version only to be get merged in the already uploaded document as it will be time consuming if one downloads the same 
document of 500 MB and make some little changes and then upload the entire document again.

How to achieve this in .net?

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling the google WebAPI

List of revisions

```
GET  /files/{fileId}/revisions
```

Retrieving a particular revision

```
GET  /files/{fileId}/revisions/{revisionId}
```

More details at:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/#Revisions

Comment: I want to use this in my .net project so for that following worked: FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();      FileList files = request.Execute();           service.Revisions.List(files.Items[0].Id);                              here 'service' is the DriveService object.